# Random Forest won't run, error message: dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=iris$Species, p=0.7, list=F)
training <- iris[inTrain,]
test <- iris[-inTrain,]
modFit <- train(Species~., data=training,method="rf",prox=F)
modFit
irisP <- classCenter(training[, c(3,4)], training$Species,modFit$finalModel$prox)
```

I was trying to use the function classCenter, but somehow it gave me an error message:

```
  Error in apply(prox, 1, order, decreasing = TRUE) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I am really confused, because I didn't use the apply function in my code. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Error: could not find function "createDataPartition"`. By the way, try `modFit$finalModel$proximity` instead of `modFit$finalModel$prox`.

Comment: you need to install the Caret package to use the function"createDataPartition"

Comment: Yes, of course, but it is your part to make your example reproducible. Please add the call to `caret` and `randomForest` packages in your original post.

Comment: In `train()`, you asked to not calculate the proximity `prox=F`. So you cannot use `classCenter`. Try with `prox=TRUE`.